# How I can make an intro logotype animation like skype app?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, splash-screen

I want to question if someone knows how I can make an intro logotype animation like as the skype app? I try to do an animation with an XML with looped images, but it is shown really weird.

Someone can tell me an advice?

Thank you for all.

P.D.: I mean to make an animation like the one shown in the video from the second 6 of the next video.

[Video of Skype for Android](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7jemPb4QQc)

Comment: well, what have you done, what happens, what do you expect, what have you tried to get the result you expect? all these questions need to be asked, and your question needs a bit more context.

Comment: I have added new info.

Comment: Did you read the FAQ or not? BE honest! This question is still bad. So you won't get any answers. Don't take this as an offensive act, I'm just telling the hard truth that if your question is bad you won't get help.

Comment: I want to do an animation as a splashscreen in my app, like the one which has the skype app in the video. My problem is that I don't know how to do that. I'm looking for some tutorials or something.

I'm sorry, but I don't know what more I need to post. And I don't feel offended. :)

Comment: I have my app finished, and now I want to add a splashscreen and the most of the tutorials that I have read in google tells the same type of animation of static images (in loop) and I want to know I there is some tutorial to make animations like the skype app. Only that Gizmo. And this question is about programming, I think. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope below link will help you to start with

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidAnimation/article.html